# Passing data between functions and callbacks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab-guide

I am new to MATLAB GUI building and I am trying to learn how to pass data between two GUIs.
My question is how to call a function in the main GUI from a sub GUI.

For example:

In the main GUI, I am getting the values from two text box from their respective callbacks as such:

```
handles.A= str2double(get(handles.textbox1,'string'));  

guidata(hObject,handles)

handles.B = str2double(get(handles.textbox2,'string'));   

guidata(hObject, handles)
```

then in addition to the above, I have a third function that does addition as such:

```
function addition(handles)    

C= handles.A + handles.B
```

The third function however is being accessed from the sub GUI through a button push as follows:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)   

main_gui('addition');
```

The error I am getting is not enough input arguments in the line `C = handles.A + handles.B`, but I don't know why I am getting this error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `addition` without any input arguments. One way pass data between your GUIs is to pass `handles.a` and `handles.b` to the sub GUI as input arguments and then use them as input arguments to `addition`.

At the top of the sub GUI opening function (`subGUI_OpeningFCN`) add the lines:

```
handles.a = varargin{1};
handles.b = varargin{2};
```

Change the sub GUI function `pushbutton1_Callback` to:

```
main_gui('addition', handles.a, handles.b);
```

In `main_gui` change `addition` to accept two input arguments:

```
addition(handles.a,handles.b)
```

Then, also in `main_gui`,call `subGUI` like this:

```
subGUI(handles.a,handles.b);
```

Note that `addition` could be defined in a separate m file instead of in the main GUI.